# Exception in saving word document

Tags: c#, .net, openxml

When I execute the below code to save the word file following exception occurs.please help me to correct the issue.thanks.

Cannot get stream with FileMode.Create, FileMode.CreateNew, FileMode.Truncate, FileMode.Append when access is FileAccess.Read.

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, false))
{
    string docText = null;
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
    {
        docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    //Regex regexText = new Regex("<var_Date>");
    docText = docText.Replace("<var_Date>", DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd,yyyy"));

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
        sw.Write(docText);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right here:

```
WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, false))
```

The second argument is `isEditable`, you passed false. So you've opened it as read-only.

Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc562234.aspx